# How to insert #tablename in a dynamic query string

Tags: sql

I have created a dynamic Query like

```
@sQry = 'SELECT * INTO #tablename FROM Table1 '

EXEC(@sQry)
```

But the table was created with the name tablename. I want to create a temporary table with in an stored procedure and also in dynamic query some one please help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test()
{
    @sQry = 'SELECT * INTO #tablename FROM Table1 '

    EXEC(@sQry)

    SELECT * FROM #tablename  INNER JOIN Table1
}
```

Sorry for my formatting

Comment: 1. What name do you want the table to have? 2. Do you need to access the table outside the scope of the dynamic SQL?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What is your question? You state that you want create a temp table but you also state that when you run this query the temp table is created. It seems that you've reached your goal. What is it, that you want to achieve that you are unable to?

Comment: I dont want the table from outside of the stored procedure

Comment: But you need to be able to access it from outside of the dynamic SQL? Local `#temp` tables get automatically dropped when the dynamic SQL batch finishes. You would need a global `##temp` table. Why are you using dynamic SQL here anyway?

Comment: I have stored procedure. Inside that I am having dynamic sql query that will create a temp table by using that I need to retrieve some more details                                                                    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test()
{
    @sQry = 'SELECT * INTO #tablename FROM Table1 '

    EXEC(@sQry)

    SELECT * FROM #tablename  INNER JOIN Table1
}

Answer (score 1):

`EXEC(@script)`, just like `EXEC storedproc`, introduces another level of scope, outside which the temporary table created by the dynamic query is inaccessible.

Your solution would then be to create the temporary table in your stored procedure before the dynamic script, then populate it by the dynamic script, and then, back in the stored procedure, work with the resulting set.

Here's an example:

```
...
SELECT TOP (0) * INTO #tablename FROM Table1
@sQry = 'INSERT INTO #tablename SELECT * FROM Table1 '
EXEC(@sQry)
SELECT * FROM #tablename INNER JOIN Table1
...
```